# Sudden drop in MPG - 2013 Accord 4 cyl CVT

Tags: honda

MPG dropped from between 28 and 30 mpg around town to less than 20 to 22 or so. No obvious change in performance. Smell of burning fuel (I guess) in the cabin sometimes. When car first starts, it takes a minute for the display to show ANY gas mileage info, then slowly climbs to about 15 mpg, then slowly higher to between 18 and 22. A couple of times, it suddenly jumped up to its regular performance until engine was turned off. But starting again the same low mileage returned. Ideas?

Comment: There's too many things that could be happening to say for sure. Does your check engine light go on? Go get your OBD codes read and post the results.

Comment: What is the ACTUAL, calculated gas mileage? This is a data point that will show you if it's an actual consumption problem or a problem with the gauge/computer. The trip computer in my Honda is seldom within 4mpg of the actual value. The computer is always high.

Comment: I'm with Tim on this one. I had a 2008 Honda which thought it was getting about 32 for a while, then thought it was getting 45 for a while. I ended up getting about 44, calculated at the pump by distance ridden/gallons of gas burned. It might take the computer a bit to figure out exactly how much gas it's actually burning. An instantaneous fuel economy is a poor indicator of average fuel economy at any given point in time, so if you have the option, I'd recommend just using the calculated average fuel economy, and letting it run for a while before trusting it.

Comment: Thanks guys. Check engine light does not go on and the temperature gauge shows the temp is reaching normal levels. The computer has been pretty consistent over the years, whether it was displaying the actual mpg, I can't say. Today it was almost back to "normal" except displayed mpg was dropping precipitously at idle. But since I'm not noticing any performance issues I'm happy to calculate the actual mileage (like I did in the olden days) for a couple of tanks and see what I get. Thanks again for the input.

Comment: You mentioned smelling burned gas. If you're smelling gas at all from the inside of the car you have a fuel leak.